# Error:android-apt plugin is incompatible with the Android Gradle plugin. Please use 'annotationProcessor' configuration instead

Tags: android, build.gradle

hoy actualice Android Studio de 2.3 a 3.0, así mismo se actualizaron los plugins del Gradle pero en este uno de mis proyectos me muestra este error
(Error:android-apt plugin is incompatible with the Android Gradle plugin.  Please use 'annotationProcessor' configuration instead). a continuación mi muild.gradle (Module:app), gracias por la ayuda.

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 26
        buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
        defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tecnologias.uniagustapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
        "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
         }
         buildTypes {
         release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
            'proguard-rules.pro'
                }
             }
          }

       dependencies {
       compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
       androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })


    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.thoughtbot:expandablerecyclerview:1.3'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En el siguiente link tienes los pasos para migrar de apt a annotationProcessor

[From apt to annotationProcessor](https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt/wiki/Migration)

Básicamente:

1. Comprobar que tienes una versión de Gradle +2.2
2. Eliminar el plugin apt del archivo build.gradle (2 línea 'apply plugin: 'android-apt'
3. Cambiar las dependencias apt por annotationProcessor.

Espero que funcione.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha funcionado.